# Celery: how to separate different environments with different workers?

Tags: python, django, celery, celeryd

I need to route all tasks of a certain django site instance to a certain queue. My setup is as following:

- several webservers running a Django project (1.7)
- one server running celery workers (3.1.7)
- Three environments: production, staging, development. Each environment runs with a different `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, with a different `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE` setting.
- One redis instance as broker (everything in the same database)

On the "celery server", I run multiple worker instances through supervisor (simplified conf):

```
[program:production_queue]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/pth/to/src/:/pth/to/site-packages/,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=website.settings.production
command=/pth/to/python celery -A website.celery worker --events --queues myserver --loglevel WARNING --concurrency 4 -n production@celery.myserver.nl

[program:staging_queue]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/pth/to/src/:/pth/to/site-packages/,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=website.settings.staging
command=/pth/to/python celery -A website.celery worker --events --queues myserver_staging --loglevel WARNING --concurrency 1 -n staging@celery.myserver.nl

[program:development_queue]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/pth/to/src/:/pth/to/site-packages/,DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=website.settings.development
command=/pth/to/python celery -A website.celery worker --events --queues myserver_development --loglevel INFO --concurrency 1 -n development@celery.myserver.nl
```

This works, with inspection:

```
$ celery -A website.celery inspect activeues
-> production@celery.myserver.nl: OK
    * {u'exclusive': False, u'name': u'myserver', u'exchange': {u'name': u'celery', u'durable': True, u'delivery_mode': 2, u'passive': False, u'arguments': None, u'type': u'direct', u'auto_delete': False}, u'durable': True, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'no_ack': False, u'alias': None, u'queue_arguments': None, u'binding_arguments': None, u'bindings': [], u'auto_delete': False}
-> staging@celery.myserver.nl: OK
    * {u'exclusive': False, u'name': u'myserver_staging', u'exchange': {u'name': u'celery', u'durable': True, u'delivery_mode': 2, u'passive': False, u'arguments': None, u'type': u'direct', u'auto_delete': False}, u'durable': True, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'no_ack': False, u'alias': None, u'queue_arguments': None, u'binding_arguments': None, u'bindings': [], u'auto_delete': False}
-> development@celery.myserver.nl: OK
    * {u'exclusive': False, u'name': u'myserver_development', u'exchange': {u'name': u'celery', u'durable': True, u'delivery_mode': 2, u'passive': False, u'arguments': None, u'type': u'direct', u'auto_delete': False}, u'durable': True, u'routing_key': u'celery', u'no_ack': False, u'alias': None, u'queue_arguments': None, u'binding_arguments': None, u'bindings': [], u'auto_delete': False}
```

(Names accord with the CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE settings)

`website/celery.py` contains the basics (imports skipped):

```
app = Celery('proj')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

I would therefore expect tasks generated by a webserver running with the development settings, to end up only in the `development_queue`, and so on. However, I see tasks being processed by a different queue, or by all three, which is problematic.

**Are my expectations wrong in that this would be a good way to separate these tasks?** All [documentation on routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#manual-routing) is about routing different tasks to different queues, which I don't need. I need to route all tasks of a certain site (environment) to a certain queue. **What can I do to separate these environments?**

Comment: yeah i think you are correct.You can set default queue as different queue based on envirnment.So you can run consumer for each queues using `-Q queue_name`

Comment: Well, that is what I was trying (see `--queues myserver` which is the same as `-Q myserver`), but as I said, it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you had a look at the fanout_prefix and fanout_patterns options when using Redis as a broker?  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#caveats

Comment: @Carl I had not seen that option yet. It appears I can only set it to `True`. Do you know how it works? What "prefix" does it set? The docs say: "You have to set a transport option to prefix the messages so that they will only be received by the active virtual host", but what is the *active* virtual host? (What is a _virtual_ host?) Can't find it in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer from the developer of Celery here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2508, which is:

> You have to set all of `CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE`, `CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE` and `CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY`. Otherwise you will end up with three queues all bound to the same exchange and routing key.
>
> Or use the method here which will set it up explicitly:
> http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#changing-the-name-of-the-default-queue

That works!

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar set up to you but my solution is to use different RabbitMQ brokers for development, staging and production.

For example, in my personal development settings file I have:

```
CELERY_BROKER = "librabbitmq://user:user@my_machine.domain.com/"
```

In the production settings file I have:

```
CELERY_BROKER = "librabbitmq://prop:prod@main_cluster.domain.com/"
```

In my celery app module I have:

```
app = Celery('App', broker=settings.CELERY_BROKER)
```

I don't know whether this helps or not, but I saw your post on the celery-users board, and since you haven't had any other responses...

Comment: Yeah, that is what I ended up doing: using different redis databases for the broker. It works but it just felt that it should work with the DEFAULT_QUEUE setting ;-)